# How to make css motion path responsive?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i have made a prototype of an original shot from dribbble. Moving images on a path defined in css. Path was created in illustrator. how can i make motion-path adjust its size according to the screen size.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/faaezahmd/pen/QvLgXP)

Code Example

```
.el-1 {
    top: 6%;
    left: 5%;
    motion-path: path('M0.1,0.5c0,0,115.7,24.9,133,122.6');
    offset-path: path('M0.1,0.5c0,0,115.7,24.9,133,122.6');
    /*motion-offset: 0%;*/
    animation: pathy 1.2s 1 ease-in;
    animation-delay: 1.60s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it by using width as % and height as vh

Example:

```
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
```

Here's a [codepen with a responsive motion path](https://codepen.io/danwilson/pen/bwdmYo/)

Comment: I am animating <img> tag on path, setting min-height will be a issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `vh` for `viewport height` and `vw` for viewport width or you can use percentages.

```
.el-1 {
top: 6%;
left: 5%;
motion-path: path('M0.1,0.5c0,0,115.7,24.9,133,122.6');
offset-path: path('M0.1,0.5c0,0,115.7,24.9,133,122.6');
/*motion-offset: 0%;*/
animation: pathy 1.2s 1 ease-in;
animation-delay: 1.60s;
height: 20vh;
width: 20vw; // or auto, or %
}
```